# Split a comma separated list where commas in text aren't escaped

Tags: regex, perl

I'm working with legacy data which is usually in the format:

```
QID    RESPONSE
```

However on some occasions the response contains multiple values of different types:

```
01320   2,35,6,"warm"
```

I have tried using

```
my @dataRowAsList = split('\t', $_); 
my $questionID = $dataRowAsList[0];     
my $response = substr($dataRowAsList[1],0,-2);
my @thisResponse = split(',', $response);
```

on relevant cases to split the output into question and response and then each response into component parts

However I've just discovered this type of case:

```
01320   2,35,6,"warm,windy"
```

The comma in quotes is not escaped

Is there a neat way to parse this into its components?

```
2
35
6
"warm,windy"
```

Comment: Use `Text::CSV` or another CSV module.

Answer (score 9):

Quick example of [Text::CSV](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::CSV) usage with reading from a string:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature qw/say/;
use Text::CSV;

my $str = q/01320   2,35,6,"warm,windy"/;

my $csv = Text::CSV->new({auto_diag => 2});

my @fields = split " ", $str, 2;

say '$fields[0] is ', $fields[0];
say '$fields[1] is ', $fields[1];

say 'Parsed out $fields[1] is:';
$csv->parse($fields[1]);
say for $csv->fields;
```

Running this will produce:

```
$fields[0] is 01320
$fields[1] is 2,35,6,"warm,windy"
Parsed out $fields[1] is:
2
35
6
warm,windy
```

This is a non-core module, so you'll have to install it with your favorite CPAN client or your OS's package manager. If doing so doesn't automatically also install [Text::CSV_XS](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::CSV_XS), you'll probably want to do so as well to get an optimized implementation that `Text::CSV` with automatically use if present.

Answer (score -1):

In your case I will use regexp and check the group that I need, this is an example I hope it will help you

```
use warnings;
use strict;
my $string = '01320 2,35,6,"warm,windy"';

if ($string =~ /^(\d+)\t(\d+),{1}(\d+),{1}(\d+),{1}(\S+)$/gu) {
        print "$1\n$2\n$3\n$4\n$5\n\n";
}
```